# window.scrollTo not working inside useEffect - reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to execute window.scrollTo on the first render using useEffect function. I am storing the vertical offset as an integer inside localStorage, but scrolling is not working and is kept at position 0.

**Does not work on first page render:**

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.scrollTo(0, localStorage.getItem('position'));
}, []);
```

It is worth noting that if I put the scroll function inside a function and call it through a button onClick it works.

**This works if called from onClick:**

```
const setScroll = () => {    
  window.scrollTo(0, localStorage.getItem('position'));
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Is there any `localStorage.getItem('position')` value set? Should it be JSON parsed? What exactly isn't working? Please be more specific. What/where is this value saved into localStorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `useEffect` function gets called the page hasn't been rendered, yet. Try calling `window.scrollTo` on the next frame:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => window.scrollTo(0, localStorage.getItem('position')), 0);
}, []);
```

Comment: This helped me solve the problem! The only modification I made is to set timeout to more than 100ms. Thank You!